# Why doesn't play video in real device by URL?

Tags: video, swift3, ios11

I am picking an video by image picker controller and then save it in document directory. I have saved file name. Then when I am trying to play this video by url device can't play this but in simulator it's playing very nicely.

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let docsurl = try! fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let path = docsurl.appendingPathComponent(contentName[indexPath.row]+extFull)
```

Here, path = file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D9878CE7-0EE5-4F67-8F3F-48772E8BBCCC/Documents/2017-11-28_18:57:25.3620.MOV

Then I have try to play this. Code is given below:

```
playVideo(filePath: path)

var videoPlayer: AVPlayer?
var avPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController?
var videoView: UIView!

func playVideo(filePath: URL) {
    self.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: filePath)
    self.avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    self.avPlayerViewController?.player = self.videoPlayer

    videoView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height-53))

    self.view.addSubview(videoView)

    avPlayerViewController?.view.frame = videoView.frame
    self.addChildViewController(avPlayerViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview((avPlayerViewController?.view)!)
}
```

avPlayerViewController is appear but why video is not play in device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **check file exist at path** before video playing,

```
func playVideo(filePath: URL) {

let fileManager = FileManager.default

if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: URL) {
    print("FILE AVAILABLE")
    self.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: filePath)
    self.avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    self.avPlayerViewController?.player = self.videoPlayer

    videoView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height-53))

    self.view.addSubview(videoView)

    avPlayerViewController?.view.frame = videoView.frame
    self.addChildViewController(avPlayerViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview((avPlayerViewController?.view)!)

} else {
    print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
}
```